# Fetch into "https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/me" showing error 400 Bad request

Tags: reactjs, facebook-graph-api, vite, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using :

- [react-facebook-login library](https://github.com/greatSumini/react-facebook-login)
- Vite v5.0.8
- React v18.0.2

Currently I'm having trouble trying to use it. I have try to use it at localhost and it works fine. But when I deploy it in Vercel, it showing error.

This is how it's look like at localhost :
[image]
This is how it's look like at live site:
[image]

this is the error response :

```
   "error": {
      "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500,
      "fbtrace_id": "AjokdMQRSMY-iM4qxnKzvry"
   }
```

this is how I use the library :

SocialComponent.jsx

```
import FacebookLogin from '@greatsumini/react-facebook-login'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import customFetch from '@/utils/customFetch'
import { jwtDecode } from 'jwt-decode'
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

export default () => {
    async function handleFacebookLogin(response) {
        const { name: full_name, email } = response
        let result = null
        try {
          result = await customFetch(
            `${import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL}/login-oauth`,
            {
              email,
              full_name,
              type: 'facebook',
            },
            'POST',
          )
          const { exp } = jwtDecode(result.token)
          const cookies = new Cookies()
          cookies.set('access_token', result.token, {
            expires: new Date(exp * 1000),
            domain: import.meta.env.VITE_TOP_LEVEL_DOMAIN,
          })

          navigate('/')
        } catch (e) {
          return Swal.fire({
            title: 'Facebook sign in failed',
            text: e.message,
            icon: 'error',
            confirmButtonText: 'Try again',
          })
        }
      }
    }
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    return (
        <FacebookLogin
            className="flex items-center justify-center rounded-md bg-blue-600 px-4 py-2 text-white transition-colors duration-300 hover:bg-blue-900"
            appId={import.meta.env.VITE_FACEBOOK_APP_ID}
            onSuccess={(response) => {
              console.log('Login Success!', response)
            }}
            onFail={(error) => {
              console.log('Login Failed!', error)
            }}
            onProfileSuccess={(response) => {
              //   handleFacebookLogin(response)
              console.log(response)
            }}
        >
            <FaFacebookSquare className="mr-2 text-2xl" />
            Login with Facebook
        </FacebookLogin>
        )
```

customFetch.js

```
export default async function (url, body = {}, method = 'GET') {
  const fetchOption = {
    method,
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  }
  if (Object.keys(body).length > 0) fetchOption.body = JSON.stringify(body)
  const response = await fetch(url, fetchOption)
  const result = await response.json()
  if (!response.ok) {
    // throw new Error(result.message)
    const error = new Error(result.message || 'Failed to fetch')
    error.response = result
    throw error
  }
  return result
}
```

*note

if I explain it wrongly and there's a missing information please tell me. I try my best to write this question, thanks.

I have try to copy the link at the livesite and try it in postman and it works fine.
But I try to use fetch in browser browser console, it gives error 400 (the same error like before).

I expect it to not give error 400

Comment: I tried to use a [token debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/) by facebook and add my token there to make sure my access_token is valid. It works withour any error.